# Moving data to another table after saveupdate with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I'm having a project where I'm using NHibernate as an ORM in my repositories. But after some [CQRS](http://cqrs.codeplex.com/) reading I want to try and "copy" some of my data to other tabels for view quering/reporting.
Meaning, when for instance a new customer is created, I would like some of the customer and company information copied to another table, using some joins, just for the purpose of quering them later without having to join and traverse all the way through some different [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)s and other layers, see CQRS :)

Now the issue is, how I should implement this? I could make some stored procedure, syncCustomer, to call after my Create Customer is done, but is this the way to go?

How else could I do this?

Comment: When you do it like this, you miss the RS of CQRS, maybe you can read some more about CQRS and event sourcing.

Comment: You might like this example if you don't know already: http://github.com/MarkNijhof/Fohjin
It's an example of cqrs with minimal amount of tools. It's useful to learn more about the concept, but you would probably like to implement it different with tools like nhibernate and a servicebus in a real application.

Answer (score 3):

Paco is right, you should look into event sourcing and potentially using a messaging architecture to support this.  [Udi Dahan](http://www.udidahan.com) has some great articles that really helped me to understand these concepts better.

In fact, the latest post is about exactly this: http://www.udidahan.com/2009/12/09/clarified-cqrs/

Comment: thanks, just read read the article. I think I misinterpreted the "how to" a little bit :).  I might have a look at the nservice bus

Comment: You don't have to start with a real servicebus. You can start create a small bus (+- 100 LOC) that does just what you need and study NServicebus (or some other esb) later. You can focus on CQRS with a very limited bus. NServicebus and it's concurrents will require a lot of learning hours.

Comment: Again I agree with Paco, I am also fairly new to this stuff and created my own very minimal service bus, it gives you a better idea of the architecture without the overhead.